# How can i get my php source code length?

Tags: php

I have a really large PHP script and I would like to know how many characters it has.

Is there any software that can count me how many files and chars are included in my project?

Comment: File size is the character count?

Comment: Not the file size. For example: <?php echo 'hi' ?> is 15 character. But I have hundreds of files. It would be fun to know how long is my code. :-)

Comment: @JánosTigyi how is that 15 chars? `:-/`

Comment: [phploc](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phploc) - doesn't give a character/byte count, but it is more meaningful

Comment: It has 9 alphabet and <? ?> ''...

Comment: `<?php echo 'hi' ?>` is 18 characters, surely

Comment: Thanks for phploc... That looks good. 
Lines of code: 313744, classes 44982,

Comment: @JánosTigyi sounds great! `;-)`

Comment: If you have that many classed, you might also want to look at some static analysis tools like [pdepend](http://pdepend.org/) and [phpmd](http://phpmd.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Mark Baker, the needed solution:

`phploc`

> A tool for quickly measuring the size and analyzing the
>   structure of a PHP project.

[phploc](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phploc)